# JavaFX: 2 radio buttons are disabling a text field, when one of them is selected

Tags: java, javafx

Basically i'm trying to have a reservation form for a hotel and there are 2 choices:

- either a "couples room" with a double size bed, which can not have other beds in it or
- a room with separated beds in which you can get up to 4 beds.

This is the scene: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHk0Z.jpg

I've been trying to make a text field "Nombre de lits". It should be disabled whenever the radio button "couple" is selected. It should be enabled when i click on the radio button "Lits separés". But the textfield stays disabled, even when i click on that button.

I've been trying to get this working but had no luck. This is my code:

```
package controleur;

import java.time.LocalDate; import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

import accesBD.ClientDAO; import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings; import javafx.beans.binding.BooleanBinding; import javafx.event.ActionEvent; import javafx.fxml.FXML; import javafx.scene.control.Button; import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker; import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton; import javafx.scene.control.TextField; import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup; import metier.Client;

public class ReservationControleur {

    private ClientDAO bd = new ClientDAO();

    @FXML
    private TextField nom;

    @FXML
    private TextField prenom;

    @FXML
    private TextField nationalite;

    @FXML
    private DatePicker datedebut;

    @FXML
    private TextField numtel;

    @FXML
    private DatePicker datefin;

    @FXML
    private RadioButton couple;

    @FXML
    private RadioButton litss;

    @FXML
    private RadioButton douche;

    @FXML
    private RadioButton bain;

    @FXML
    private TextField nbrlits;

    @FXML
    private RadioButton standard;

    @FXML
    private RadioButton inclusive;

    @FXML
    private RadioButton vip;

    @FXML
    private Button valider;

    @FXML
    private Button anuuler;
    private ToggleGroup group = new ToggleGroup(); 
    private ToggleGroup group1 = new ToggleGroup();

    @FXML   private void isClicked(ActionEvent event){

    }

    public void initialize() {

        datedebut.setValue(LocalDate.now());

        couple.setToggleGroup(group);
        couple.setSelected(true);
        litss.setToggleGroup(group);
        douche.setToggleGroup(group1);
        bain.setToggleGroup(group1);
        douche.setSelected(true);
        if(couple.isSelected())
            nbrlits.setDisable(true);
        else
            nbrlits.setDisable(false);
        }


    @FXML
    void confirmer(ActionEvent event) {
        int ntel = Integer.parseInt(numtel.getText());
        Client c = new Client(nom.getText(), prenom.getText(), nationalite.getText(), ntel);
        bd.add(c);
    }

    @FXML
    void remiseazero(ActionEvent event) {

    }
}
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that checks which RadioButton is selected is executed only once - when ReservationControleur is initialized, and that's not what you need.

You want to change "nbrlits" TextView's state to "disabled" every time "couple" RadioButton is selected, so you need to bind those two properties together.

Change this:

```
if(couple.isSelected())
    nbrlits.setDisable(true);
else
    nbrlits.setDisable(false);
}
```

into this:

```
//set "nbrlits" to disabled state each time "couple" radiobutton is selected
nbrlits.disableProperty().bind(couple.selectedProperty());
```